# Python json.dumps adding backslash

Tags: c#, python, json, serialization

My c# code using Python Provider with 3.5 version. 
I am sending REST request to my Python Provider, and I getting a weird response with to many backslashes, like the following:

This is how the response looks in my c# code

```
"\"{\\\"IsSuccess\\\": true, \\\"Value\\\": null, \\\"ErrorCode\\\": 0, \\\"ErrorMessage\\\": \\\"\\\", \\\"RequestId\\\": \\\"09ea4b59-52a9-4796-a967-62317457ea91\\\"}\"\n"
```

In my Python Provider I using

```
json.dumps(object2Serialize.__dict__)
```

in order the info to be serialized.
Any ideas why I am getting the object in my C# code like this?

Comment: Looks as if the resulting JSON has been serialized again ... twice. W/o the python code it's hard to say where this is happening. You might have to debug the application to see where your JSON is passed along.

Comment: @MikeScotty That the problem, while debugging my python app I don`t see any backslash in the object.